# HTML - Input-form for URL

Tags: javascript, html, forms, list, firebase-realtime-database

#### What

I want to copy an URL (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com) into an input-field/form and display the clickable link in a list after submitting.
On submission, the content of the input-field is saved to a Firebase backend which items are displayed in a list.

#### Problem

I thought I could use input-type="url", but it does not work.
All I get after submission is a String.

Any of you having a solution for this issue, ideally using HTML + JavaScript and jQuery?

**Here's my code so far:**

```js
// Create Firebase reference
var dbRef = new Firebase("...");
var contactsRef = dbRef.child('contacts')

// Load all items
contactsRef.on("child_added", function(snap) {
  console.log("added", snap.key(), snap.val());
  document.querySelector('#contacts').innerHTML += (contactHtmlFromObject(snap.val()));
});

// Save items
document.querySelector(".addValue").addEventListener("click", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if( document.querySelector('#url').value != 'url' || document.querySelector('#email').value != '' ){
    contactsRef
      .push({
        name: document.querySelector('#url').value,
              })
      contactForm.reset();
  } else {
    alert('Please fill at least name or email!');
  }
}, false);

// Prepare items object's HTML
function contactHtmlFromObject(contact){
  console.log( contact );
     // Resulting string
  var html = '';
  html += '<li class="list-group-item contact">';
    html += '<div>';
      html += '<p class="lead">'+contact.name+'</p>';
      html += '<p>'+contact.email+'</p>';
    html += '</div>';
  html += '</li>';
  return html;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>frontendpublishing-test</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.embed.ly/jquery.preview-0.3.2.css" />
  <style type="text/css">
    #contacts p,
    #contacts p.lead{
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Title h1</h1>
    <hr/>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <form method="post" name="contactForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="url"  type="url" required name="url">          </input>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary addValue">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <div class="col-md-6">
        <ul id="contacts" class="list-group">
          <!-- Contact Object li.list-group-item.contact will be added here by js -->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include Firebase Library -->
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.3/firebase.js"></script>
  <!-- Contacts Store JavaScript -->
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/urldata.previewer.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/urldata.previewer.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will always get a string on `input[type="text"]` and `input[type="url"]`. In order to show a link you have to wrap your URLs in an `<a>` tag, or else it will just display a text that is not clickable.

Comment: Yes, you´re right.
But even when I change the tag it does not work.
The items are clickable but does not direct to any url.

thanks

Comment: Not only you have to wrap them in `<a>` tags, you have to add the url to the `href` attribute to the `<a>`. So in all you will have to spit out the link twice. `<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">https://stackoverflow.com</a>`

Comment: works for me!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your output link into a valid anchor:

```
<a href="http://example.org">http://example.org</a>
```